# Is AcquireTokenAsync thread-safe?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using ADAL's (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v4.3.0) `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync` to acquire a bearer token with a `ClientCredential`.

I am creating a new `AuthenticationContext` to acquire a token for each request. Is that thread-safe? Or do I have to lock the call to `AcquireTokenAsync` with a static `SemaphoreSlim`?

I am asking because according to http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/01/getting-acquainted-with-adals-token-cache/ the method uses a static token cache which is **not** thread-safe, but the article is quite old and I haven't found any more up-to-date information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADAL.NET v4.3 can not at this point in time be considered thread safe. We are working towards this with MSAL v2+.

Comment: Another [relevant conversation here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1330)