# Is ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient().ExecuteAsync() thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, azure-ad-msal

For service to service auth using a bearer token for the app (client id and secret no user context) in .net core using MSAL.NET v4 (nuget Microsoft.Identity.Client v4.3.0) is `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient().ExecuteAsync()` safe to use in a singleton registered service implemented like this?

```
public class AADConfidentialClient : IServiceApiAuthorizer
    {
        private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClient;
        public AADConfidentialClient(IOptions<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions> options)
        {
            _confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                     .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options.Value)
                     .Build();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(IReadOnlyCollection<string> scopes)
        {
            var result = await _confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
```

Registered with the .net core built-in DI as

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceApiAuthorizer, AADConfidentialClient>();
```

I've seen this answer for ADAL.NET https://stackoverflow.com/a/53163274/184220 which mentions working towards thread safety for MSAL v2+ but haven't found anything confirming if this has been done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `client credentials flow` this uses it is safe to be a singleton. I eventually found this question in the GitHub issues https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1342 which was about the `on behalf of flow` which had this answer to one of the questions:

> You should have 1 Confidential Client Application for each token cache. And we recommend that you have 1 token cache per session, so there should be 1 CCA per session.

As the implementation in this question essentially has 1 token cache I thought it would be safe but asked for confirmation anyway and this https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1342#issuecomment-525286547 was the answer:

> yes, for Client Credentials flow a singleton should work fine. You are requesting tokens for an application, not for a user. There will only be 1 access token in the in-memory cache (for the app), irrespective of how many users and sessions there are

Answer (score 1):

In MSAL.NET v2, the `ConfidentialClientApplication` class had numerous methods for acquiring a token and multiple overloads per method with the many optional parameters.  Similar to the new fluent syntax for `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`, it is now possible to specify required parameters in the primary `AcquireToken_xxx_()` method with optional parameters in follow-on method calls with a final call to `ExecuteAsync()`.

```
authResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

The above changes were the minimal amount of code changes required to [upgrade to MSAL .NET v3 or v4](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-upgrading-to-msal-net-v4/).

So it is safe in MSAL.NET v4. You could also refer to the [v4 release](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-4).

Comment: Hi, there is no upgrade of MSAL versions here this is for a new code base. I've read those docs and also https://aka.ms/msal-net-client-credentials none of which mention thread safety. Do you have any links that specifically say if the client or token acquisition is thread safe?